# Do we want the comparison tag?

Tags: discussion, tags

There are currently [two](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/14489/why-someone-would-choose-freebsd) [questions](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/13554/how-does-the-unix-file-privilege-system-differ-from-that-of-windows) tagged [comparison](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/comparison). When I saw the tag name, I expected them to be about tools like `cmp` and `diff` (i.e. should be a synonym of [diff](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/diff)). The tag actually means “comparison between a unix system and some other system”, which feels like [meta-tags](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/08/the-death-of-meta-tags/). I'm not dead set against it, but I find the name counterintuitive, and I don't really find it useful.

Burninate, rename, keep?

Comment: I'd vote for Burminate, with a note that we also have the similar [distro-choice] tag.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I say zap it. Too many possible things to compare, and nothing really tying them together. How is that ever useful?